# Disable Rails 3.1 asset pipeline for images only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm upgrading a Rails 3 app to 3.2 and setting up the asset pipeline. It's great for css/js but I don't really see the point in using it for images, and unfortunately I have css with a ton of references /images/*.png and the like.

Is there a way to disable the asset pipeline just for images so `image_tag("x.png")` will go back to returning `<img src="/images/x.png">` instead of `<img src="/assets/x.png">`? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can monkey-patch ActionView::Base, try this in rails console:

```
helper.image_path "foo" #=> "/assets/foo"

module OldImagePath
  def image_path(source)
    asset_paths.compute_public_path(source, 'images')
  end
  alias_method :path_to_image, :image_path
end
ActionView::Base.send :include, OldImagePath

helper.image_path "foo" #=> "/images/foo"
```

You can place this in an initializer for example. By default ActionView::Base includes ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper and Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper which both define image_path but the latter take precedence. I'm including my own module which take precedence over all of them (the code inside is taken from ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper).

Although, it makes sense to use asset pipeline for images too. They get hash sum in their filenames so that they can be cached forever on the client side without asking the server whether the file was changed.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this works? I ended up biting the bullet and embracing the asset pipeline for images as well.

Comment: Thanks!  I used this technique to keep an AssetNotPrecompiledError from producing a 500 server error in production, if an error occurs resolving an image path through the asset pipeline.  In my override of image_path, I just call 'super(source)', but add a rescue clause that logs the error and returns "#" for the path.  I put the 'ActionView::Base.send' line into an initializer, as you suggested.  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this gem:
https://github.com/spohlenz/digestion, it should do what you need :).

Otherwise you can move the assets you don't want included in the asset pipeline from app/assets back into public (e.g. public/images). Everything should work as you expect without the need for a gem.